# Binary tree post fix to infix

Tags: java, binary-tree, java.util.scanner, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to add a `Scanner` so user input is accepted but I'm running into an issue with this algorithm that I don't know how to solve. The line

```
char[] charArray = postfix.toCharArray();
```

is getting an error

> the method toCharArray() is undefined for the type Scanner.

I am just playing with this code I found so that I can add user input so I know there must be something I forgot besides that. Any insight?

```
package binaryTree;
//Java program to construct an expression tree

import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;
//Java program for expression tree
class Node {

char value;
Node left, right;

Node(char item) {
    value = item;
    left = right = null;
}
}

class ExpressionTree {

// A utility function to check if 'c'
// is an operator

boolean isOperator(char c) {
    if (c == '+' || c == '-'
            || c == '*' || c == '/'
            || c == '^') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Utility function to do inorder traversal
void inorder(Node t) {
    if (t != null) {
        inorder(t.left);
        System.out.print(t.value + " ");
        inorder(t.right);
    }
}

// Returns root of constructed tree for given
// postfix expression
Node constructTree(char postfix[]) {
    Stack<Node> st = new Stack<Node>();
    Node t, t1, t2;

    // Traverse through every character of
    // input expression
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length; i++) {

        // If operand, simply push into stack
        if (!isOperator(postfix[i])) {
            t = new Node(postfix[i]);
            st.push(t);
        } else // operator
        {
            t = new Node(postfix[i]);

            // Pop two top nodes
            // Store top
            t1 = st.pop();   // Remove top
            t2 = st.pop();

            // make them children
            t.right = t1;
            t.left = t2;

            // System.out.println(t1 + "" + t2);
            // Add this subexpression to stack
            st.push(t);
        }
    }

    // only element will be root of expression
    // tree
    t = st.peek();
    st.pop();

    return t;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();
    Scanner postfix = new Scanner (System.in);
    char[] charArray = postfix.toCharArray();
    Node root = et.constructTree(charArray);
    System.out.println("infix expression is");
    et.inorder(root);

 }
}
```

Comment: Why have you named a variable of type `Scanner` as `postfix`? This already doesnt make any sense. And then why are you trying to convert it to a `char[]` without doing any I/O?

Comment: im not sure i just am trying to figure out how to allow for user input from a postfix to infix expression.

Comment: What does the user input you're trying to read look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: A Scanner is not a String, and it doesn't have a toCharArray() method.

Comment: Input:ab+ef*g*-     output:a + b - e * f * g

Answer (score 0):

The following code will simply resolve the error you are getting. It is only the changes you should make to your method `main`.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Added this line.
    String postfix = scanner.nextLine(); // Changed this line.
    char[] charArray = postfix.toCharArray();
    Node root = et.constructTree(charArray);
    System.out.println("infix expression is");
    et.inorder(root);
 }
```

The error message...

> the method toCharArray() is undefined for the type Scanner

means that class `java.util.Scanner` does **not** contain a method named `toCharArray()`.

Class `java.util.Scanner` contains method `nextLine()` which reads a line of text input by the user via the standard input stream which is usually the computer keyboard.

Method `nextLine()` returns a string and class `java.lang.String` contains method `toCharArray()`.